# Does php contact form need to be live for it to work?

Tags: php, form-submit

I tried making my contact form work. It's in my landing page that I designed, but I haven't upload it to server yet. I only wanted to test if the contact form work, but every time I try to submit the form, I get a popup window asking me to download the contact.php. Is it because I used "Preview in browser" command from Dreamweaver to test out the landing page and contact form?

I used php from http://codechirps.com/php-email-contact-form-tutorial/. And if it's not working, I might also use http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-neat-html5-powered-contact-form--net-20426.

Comment: You can use software such as XAMPP to test PHP on your machine before uploading it to your server. Check out this link: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is going to submit that form to whatever file is specified in the form's `action` attribute.

But you WILL have to have loaded the page via an HTTP request. A local `file://` request is NOT an HTTP request, and any post/put/head-type request you do to it will simply be treated as a "get", and without any webserver to actually execute the PHP code in that script, your browser will simply pop up a download prompt. `.php` isn't a known file type as far as your browser is concerned, and you're getting the standard "I have no idea what to do with this" action.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I thought that may be the case but I just want to make sure and to get a more detailed explanation to what happened.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't necessarily have to be live — a development server is fine — but do you need to load your server-side code through a server for it to work.